how to retrieve ReadableStream data from res.body in JS
I am fetching data from my backend using fetch function and it returns a readableStream as response's body. How can I extract the data in that readable stream?
I've tries using res.json method, but it returns undefined.
Here's my fetch call -
fetch('/playground',{
      method: 'POST',
    }).then(function(res){
      res.json()
    }).then(data => console.log(data))

it returns undefined in the console.
Here's the code from node.js server
router.route('/playground')
.post((req,res)=>{
    res.send({message: 'Hello from backend'})
})

I was expecting it to give me output as an object with key value pair as
{
  message: "Hello from backend"
}

but it returns undefined
------------UPDATE------------------------------
here's my entire router code, for a comment asked for it.
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const{scriptArray} = require('../Scripts/main')

router.route('/')
.get((req, res) =>{
    res.render('homepage')
})

router.route('/playground')
.get((req, res) =>{
    res.render('playground', {value: JSON.stringify(scriptArray)})
})
.post((req,res)=>{
    // console.log(req);
    res.send({message: 'Hello from backend'})
})

module.exports = {
    router,
}


share the entire code of  the script where you defined router without which it is not possible to say what has gone wrong.

I am pretty much sure my route is regestired properly, because, even in backend I put a console.log(request) and it was printing the request object in the terminal, whenever I fetched in that url. But anyways I updated my question with entire router code

You're not returning properly! Do this:
return res.json();


THANKS!!! man, now I feel so silly but you owe me this one.
